# Having a lot of trouble getting my QR Scanner to work

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I can't seem to get my program to work properly...
I'm working on a Point of Sale system and I need to scan an article, and display this in my WPF C# program.
I have working code, but the strange thing is that when I scan multiple times in a row that I get two message boxes (debugging) instead of one. My code is as following:
The following code initializes my Serialport, but doesn't open a connection to it:

```
private void Cb1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cb1.SelectedItem.ToString())) { MessageBox.Show("Er is nog niet een selectie gemaakt "); }
    else
    {
        sp = new SerialPort(cb1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        sp.BaudRate = 9600;
        sp.DataBits = 8;
        sp.Parity = Parity.None;
        sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        disconnect.IsEnabled = true; //Irrelevant
    }
}
```

I've made the following button that checks if the connection is open. If the connection to the serial port isn't open, it will connect and add a event handler that awaits data:

```
private void Artikel_Scan(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(sp != null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!sp.IsOpen)
            {
                sp.Open();
                sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(artikel_DataReceived);
            }
            else
                sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(artikel_DataReceived);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Configure the QR Scanner Please.");
    }
}
```

And the following code prints the received data inside a messagebox:

```
private void artikel_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[20];
    Action kickoffRead = null;
    kickoffRead = delegate
    {
        sp.BaseStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, delegate (IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                try
                {
                    int actualLength = sp.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);
                    byte[] received = new byte[actualLength+1];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, received, 0, actualLength);
                    RaiseAppSerialDataEvent(received);
                }
                catch (IO.IOException exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR == > " + exc.ToString());
                }
                kickoffRead();
            }, null);
    };
    kickoffRead();
}

private void RaiseAppSerialDataEvent(byte[] Data)
{
    string Result = Encoding.Default.GetString(Data);
    MessageBox.Show(Result);
    /*Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        artikeltxt.Text = Result;
    }));*/
}
```

I close my port using the following code:

```
sp.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(artikel_DataReceived);
```

I have two QR-codes with the following information:

- 5039085 rev.-
- 5034917

The first time I scan the first QR-code, I get just one Messagebox showing the full contents of the QR-code. Sometimes when I scan the second QR-code it also shows the full contents of the QR-code. It does however sometimes happen that I get 2 separate Messagebox showing part of the information of one of the QR-codes.

I have a Datalogic Quickscan 2430 QR-Scanner configured using USB-COM as interface and the Trigger mode is Trigger single.

What can I do to fix my problem? I'm kinda new to serial programming so I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

EDIT: While testing various things, I think I broke my scanner. My scanner keeps reconnecting to windows. When I open Device manager, it appears shortly and then disappears continuously. Hope the manufacturer can fix my scanner...

Edit 2: I've managed to fix my issues with the help of @Baddack. I've put all my Serial code inside a class, and call the functions in my mainwindow.xaml. I have a button that executes the following function:

```
public void Artikel_Scan(TextBox tb1)
{
    tbartikel = tb1;
    if (!isSerialNull())
    {
        try
        {
            if (!isSerialOpen())
            {
                sp.Open();
                sp.DataReceived += new IO.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(artikel_DataReceived);
            }
            else
                sp.DataReceived += new IO.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(artikel_DataReceived);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my DataReceived function that launches another function using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke:

```
private void artikel_DataReceived(object sender, IO.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string data = sp.ReadExisting();
    data = data.Replace("\r", string.Empty);
    data = data.Replace("\n", string.Empty);
    data = data.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
    data = IllegalCharacterCheck(data);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
    {
        string payload = data.Substring(1, data.Length - 1);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => artikelDatareceived(payload)));
    }
}

private void artikelDatareceived(string payload)
{
    tbartikel.Text = payload;
}
```

After the textbox is filled with text, a TextChanged event is called that closes my serialport connection and disposes it:

```
public void artikel_Close()
{
    sp.DataReceived -= new IO.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(artikel_DataReceived);
    sp.Close();
    sp.Dispose();
}
```

I have tested it and it works perfectly now.

Comment: I think you're creating multiple `DataReceived` events everytime you scan, which is why when you scan again it fires that event multiple times.  Put the creation of your event somewhere it will only get called once, having it in your scan method is causing the issue.

Comment: I've added the serial.Open() to my initialization code (the first code example in my answer), tried it again and it still happened. I've also added the last code example to my DataReceived function. After receiving data, it closes the datahandler. It did not fix my problem. When I scan the code 5034917 a few times, it sometimes happens that I get two message boxes. The first contains a '5', while the second messagebox contains '034917'

Comment: If you use a scanner in a POS application, it is better to use the Unified POS API instead of using the COM port directly. The specification is here [Document -- retail/17-07-32 (UnifiedPOS Retail Peripheral Architecture, Version 1.14.1)](https://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?retail/2017-07-32), and the device driver will be available here [OPOS MR5 1.14.171 (23/04/2019) OPOS drivers for Datalogic scanners/scales for all supported interfaces. Resolution of various defects.](https://www.datalogic.com/eng/Download/Form/22897).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't update your code above, so I'm not sure exactly what you changed.  But I think the key is you can only call `sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(artikel_DataReceived);` once, otherwise it's going to subscribe to that event multiple times.

Do a simple test, create a form with 2 buttons and a textbox.  Use the code below and press the open button, do some scans, then close it.  Let me know the results.

```
SerialPort sp;

private void buttonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sp != null)
        return;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cb1.SelectedItem.ToString())) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Er is nog niet een selectie gemaakt ");
        return;
    }

    sp = new SerialPort();
    sp.PortName = "COM1";   //put your comport # here
    sp.BaudRate = 9600;
    sp.DataBits = 8;
    sp.Parity = Parity.None;
    sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(artikel_DataReceived);

    sp.Open();
}

private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sp.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(artikel_DataReceived);
    sp.Close();
    sp.Dispose();
}

private void artikel_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string Data = sp.ReadExisting();

    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        textBox1.Text += Data;
    });
}
```

Comment: I made a new project and had to edit `this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        textBox1.Text += Data;
    });` to `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
            {
                scan.Text = Data;
            }));`. However, when I tried testing it, my scanner broke. I've just sent it to the manufacturer for repairs.

Comment: My scanner is fixed, I've set it up as interface USB-COM, and tried to scan my two QR-codes one after another, the result I've gotten: [link](https://imgur.com/a/k0Md2ND), so strangely I'm getting a weird 'y'-character.

Comment: It's not exactly the same as you described, but closing and disposing my serialport connection was the key to fixing my problem. I've updated my code and I'll accept this solution.